# ggplot layers interfere one with the other

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm plotting a big plot, and for some reason some of the data disappears.

I played a little and found out that if I remove other layers, the data appears again. any idea way this is happening?

The plot, missing some of the data

[image: The plot, missing some of the data]

The plot with the data after I removed the other layers (green and black lines)

[image: The plot with the data]

This is the relevant code- (I would have put a reproducible example, if I knew how, I'm not sure what is causing it, and how to reproduce it)

```
main_plot <- ggplot(seg) + facet_grid(id~chr, scales='free_x')

# KNN
# remove KNN rows that don't contain anything (after faceting)
seg <- seg[!(grepl('KNN', seg$id, fixed = TRUE) & seg$log2 == 0),]
 # check that there are KNN line before ploting
if(sum(grepl("KNN", seg$id,fixed=TRUE))) {
  main_plot <- main_plot + 
    geom_segment(data=seg[grepl("KNN",seg$id,fixed=TRUE),],
                 mapping=aes(x=start,xend=end,y=0,yend=0,size=3,color=((log2>0) - 0.5)*6))
}
# scatter
###main_plot <- main_plot + geom_segment(data=seg[grepl("hits",seg$id, fixed = TRUE),],
###                                    mapping=aes(x=start,xend=end,y=log2,yend=log2, size = 2),color='chartreuse3')
# median with smothing
###    if(sum(median_data_with_smoothing$median_color == 'red') > 0) {
###main_plot <- main_plot + geom_segment(data=median_data_with_smoothing[median_data_with_smoothing$median_color == 'red',], 
###                                     mapping=aes(x=start, xend=end, y=median, yend=median,size=2), color='red')
###}
###if(sum(median_data_with_smoothing$median_color == 'cyan') > 0) {
###main_plot <- main_plot + geom_segment(data=median_data_with_smoothing[median_data_with_smoothing$median_color == 'cyan',], 
###                                     mapping=aes(x=start, xend=end, y=median, yend=median,size=2), color='cyan')
###}
###if(sum(median_data_with_smoothing$median_color == 'black') > 0) {
###main_plot <- main_plot + geom_segment(data=median_data_with_smoothing[median_data_with_smoothing$median_color == 'black',], 
###                                        mapping=aes(x=start, xend=end, y=median, yend=median,size=2), color='black')
###}
# adding more layers
main_plot <- main_plot + 
  scale_color_gradient2(limits=c(-3,3),low="cyan",mid="gray60",high="red",na.value="deeppink",midpoint=0) +
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="white")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(panel.spacing=unit(2, "points")) +
  ylab("") + 
  ylim(c(-2,2))
```

The parts of the code that have ### are the layers I removed and the data appeared.

The data is from a 2 very big `data.table`s, (300K lines) so I can't upload it somehow.

Comment: You can use `dput()` to create a reproducible example. Here's some example code using it: https://gist.github.com/dsparks/3688652

You don't have to upload all the data just the data that is related to the problem.

Comment: That is exactly the problem, when I remove some of the data the problem disappears, it's very confusing. It's not the first time that I experience this kind of behavior with ggplot2.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth trying to have "free" in  `facet_grid(id~chr, scales="free")` so that both the x-axis and the y-axis are free to be whatever limit the data needs to fit to. It's very difficult to see what the problem is. However, I suspect it may be something along those lines. Failing that, perhaps upload the data, or `dput()` of the data, to github and link the code into your question so that it can be copied here.

Only other thing I can think on is that your data shaping code is doing something you don't expect it to do. Try shaping using another approach.

Comment: @Docconcoct, first of all, thank you very mach, I changed the scales to free, and removed the `ylim(c(-2,2))` and that fixed the problem. I'm just wandering, I wasn't using anything in the y axis, `aes(y=0,yend=0)`, so it's not that I'm out of the range (-2,2). any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Ok, it solved some of the problem, not all of it.
I'll try to upload the data somehow

Comment: Glad there has been some progress. The scales suggestion was a bit of an educated stab in the dark. I have no real notion as to what was happening without seeing the data. I'll see if I can figure it out once your data is linked. Just @ me here so I'm alerted.

Comment: @Docconcoct, sorry I didn't respond, I had a very busy week.
I finally found the problem(just now), because I'm plotting all the segments in the same y coordinate (0), the segments hide each other. if I add `jitter()` that solves the problem. (but takes a long time producing all the random numbers)

Thank you very very much for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You might as well answer your own question below and mark it answered in a couple of days so other people can solve similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I plot all the segments in the same Y coordinate (0), and ggplot treats the segments like discrete values, or something similar.

I added some noise to the data with `jitter()` and then I could see all the data in the plot.

Here is my code-

```
if(sum(grepl("KNN", seg$id,fixed=TRUE))) {
  main_plot <- main_plot + 
    geom_segment(data=seg[grepl("KNN",seg$id,fixed=TRUE),],
                 mapping=aes(x=start,xend=end,y=jitter(log2/100, amount=0.00001),yend=jitter(log2/100,amount=0.00001),size=3,color=((log2>0) - 0.5)*6))
}
```

The values of the log2 are 1 and -1, so I divided it by 100 to get close enough to 0, and added noise in much smaller scale so it will not be visible.

The reason that when I removed some of the data (scatter and median) I saw all the KNN data is because the scale changed (the scales depends on the data that you plot)